# AWK or GREP 1 instance of repeated output

Tags: csv, awk

so what I have here is some output from a cisco switch and I need to capture the host name and use that to populate a csv file. 
basically I run a show mac address-table and pull mac addresses and populate them into a csv file. that I got however I cant figure out how to grab the host name so that I can put that in a separate column.
I have done this:

```
awk '/#/{print $1}'
```

but that will print every line that has '#' in it. I only need 1 to populate a variable so I can re use it. the end result needs to look like this: (the CSV file has MAC address, port number , hostname. I use commas to indicate the column seperation

```
    0011.2233.4455,Gi1/1,Switch1#
    0011.2233.4488,Gi1/2,Switch1#
    0011.2233.4499,Gi1/3,Switch1#
```

Comment: Its not cleat what is you input data and how like your output data to bee.  Post some more data.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the input file looks like, the exact solution that is required will be uncertain. However, as an example, given an input file like the requested output (which I've called `switch.txt`):

```
0011.2233.4455,Gi1/1,Switch1#
0011.2233.4488,Gi1/2,Switch1#
0011.2233.4499,Gi1/3,Switch1#
0011.2233.4455,Gi1/1,Switch3#
0011.2233.4488,Gi1/2,Switch2#
0011.2233.4498,Gi1/3,Switch3#
```

... a list of the unique values of the first field (comma-separated) can be obtained from:

```
$ awk -F, '{print $1}' <switch.txt | sort | uniq
0011.2233.4455
0011.2233.4488
0011.2233.4498
0011.2233.4499
```

An approach like this might help with extracting unique values from the actual input file.

Comment: You don't really need `sort` and `uniq`. `awk -F, '!a[$1]++ {print $1}' switch.txt` would work just fine.